# Не проходит проверку email валидации?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не снимается класс error. Не проходит валидацию. Где ошибка?

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var fname = $(".fname").val();
    var lname = $(".lname").val();
    var phone = $(".phone").val();
    var email = $(".email").val();
    let isValid = ($('.email').val().match(/.+?\@.+/g) || []).length === 1;

    if (!isValid) {
        $('.email').addClass('error')
    } else {
        $('.email').removeClass('error')
    }
})
```

Comment: где вы взяли такую проверку? слишком короткая

Comment: @КириллПанишев а как надо, трехэтажную регулярку написать, чтобы она все по каким нить RFC валидировало? кому оно надо в наше время?

Comment: Чем плоха большая регулярка? Валидность не так просто проверяется

Comment: Проверьте, получаете ли value из .email.